# Move card and its contents down

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

[I have been able to make an image protrude the top half of a card](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wp2qfv?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.scss) but the image is overlapping text and other images. How can I push the card down where the top half contains the bottom half of the image and the bottom half contains the additional text, images, etc.?

Here is my CSS:

```
.card {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 100px;
  overflow: visible;

  div {
    position: absolute;
    top: -95px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }


  img:not(.castImg) {
    width: 80%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    display: block;
    margin: -100px auto 0;
  }
}
```

I am trying to emulate this design:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create enough space for those elements to fit underneath each other while they overlap.

Personally I would wrap the image and card in a div together so you can position them as you want and apply a margin-bottom to create space between each card. But this will work based on your code.

Try this:

```
.card {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: auto;
    border-radius: 8px;

    position: relative;
    // height: 150px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 350px; /* changed */
    overflow: visible;

    div {
        position: absolute;
        top: -95px;
        width: 100%;
        // z-index: 2;
        text-align: center;
    }


    img:not(.castImg) {
        width: 50%; /* changed */
        // margin: auto;
        border-radius: 8px;

        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;


        display: block;
        // width: 128px;
        // height: 128px;
        // margin: 30px auto 0;
        margin: -200px auto 0; /* changed */
    }
}
```